# JQUERY AJAX works on linux, but not on windows box

Tags: jquery

I have a strange issue where the code works fine locally and on a linux server but not on a windows server...

Works fine on: bijoudancewear.co.uk/mapper/

Doesn't work on: faringdongolfcourse.co.uk/mapper/

After clicking on map...
If you click on 'Department Stores, fashion & Accessories' (2nd from bottom) it loads the appropriate data on the linux box but not on Windows.

Also works fine locally on my mac, there is no ASP or PHP, this is good old fashioned html and jquery.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a POST to a static file, which IIS does not allow.

You need to make a GET request, by changing `type : "POST",` to `type : "GET",`.